# Besides www and dl, what other keywords can you prepend to a url?

Tags: url, resources, navigation, html

Recently, I found that you can put dl infront of a url instead of www in order to force an image to download. I never knew this, but it was quite useful knowledge for an email template I made. Now I am curious, what other things can be put into the url bar to give additional functionality?

Comment: That's not a standard that I'm aware of.  Perhaps certain websites use that standard, but it's not universal at all.

Comment: Can you post a link to the source of this info?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/help/201/en, I suppose it is only a drop box thing then?